# Get only time data out of date and time string.

Tags: python, time

I want to get only the time data out of this date format? In the following case it is 23:55:00. I have tried many methods including `datetime.strptime` , `from dateutil import parser` etc. but failed. :( How to do it with Python?

```
[15/Apr/2013:23:55:00 +0530]
```

Comment: How is stored the "date" in your program? As a `datetime` _object_? As as a _string_? As a _timestamp_? Other?

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux I read dates from a text file and put them in to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Does your data include the brackets? And do you care about timezone information?

Comment: @Thomas Fenzl yes it has brackets, I just need to get 23:55:00 partout of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you could access the "date" as a string:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> time_string = "[15/Apr/2013:23:55:00 +0530]"

>>> format = "[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]"
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(time_string, format)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 15, 23, 55, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 19800)))

# Accessing the time as an object:
>>> the_time = dt.time()
>>> the_time
datetime.time(23, 55)

# Accessing the time as a string:
>>> the_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
'23:55:00'
```

---

If you are *positively definitively absolutely* certain the date has a *fixed* format, you could just *slice* your string:

```
>>> time_string = "[15/Apr/2013:23:55:00 +0530]"
>>> time_string[-15:-7]
'23:55:00'
```

This is only an example. Python has tons of string manipulation functions maybe more suitable with your data. Don't hesitate to take a look at them!

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux Yes :( I have python 2.7 and it gives me the following error ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]'

Comment: Is the TZ important? If not, and as it is separated from actual date by a space, you could simply do a _trick_ like that: `format = "[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"` `dt = datetime.strptime(time_string.split()[0], format)` Just replace the corresponding lines in the code. If TZ is important some more decoding is required (but according to your example, it is _not_)

Comment: I modified my answer to propose an alternative solution if you don't want to deal with time formats.

Answer (score 1):

could use a regex to grab just the time part

```
import re

date = '15/Apr/2013:23:55:00 +0530'
regex = ':(?P<time>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})'
just_time = re.search(regex, date).groupdict()['time']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interesting in the *string* and not a time object, you can do this:

```
>>> s = '[15/Apr/2013:23:55:00 +0530]'
>>> s[13:21]
23:55:00
```

You only need `datetime` if you intend to do some time calculations with the string; however as you are ignore the timezone, it sounds like all you need is the string that represents the time.

Of course, you can always convert that *into* a time object if you want:

```
>>> import time
>>> t = time.strptime(s[13:21], '%H:%M:%S')
```